# How do i fetch a document from my google drive and display it on a page using googledrive API in nextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-api, google-drive-api, backend

I have been experimenting with the documentation and watching different videos, but I'm still facing difficulties on what exactly to do. I'm a beginner to nextJS and react. I'm working on a Next.js and React project, and my goal is to fetch a document from my Google Drive using OAuth and display it on a webpage. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could simplify the process for me or provide me with resources that can help me understand how to accomplish this task effectively.

Answer (score 0):

The google drive api is a file storage api only.  It can help you insert, update, list files and folders.  It does not have access to the contents  of the files themselves.

You could download the file then use something on your system to open it and display it on the webpage in what ever format you wish.

The google docs api does have access to the contents of a google doc file for example as does the google sheets api for google sheets but this is raw data returned to you as JSON.  Its not going to look very well sitting on a webpage.

You will need to format the text to your liking.

If what you are actually trying to do is open the file within the google drive web app for that type of file then well the user needs access to that file to be able to open it and you will have to open it in drive not in a page on your website.